# disable controlpanel

Tags: c#, windows, controlpanel

i have used following code to disable the Windows Control Panel.  It successfully disables the Control Panel, but it needs a sytem restart to apply changes.  Does anybody know how I can apply these changes to the Control Panel immediately, without requiring a system restart?  Can anybody can help me?

```
        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer");
        RegKey.SetValue("NoControlPanel", true, RegistryValueKind.DWord); RegKey.Close();

        RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer");
        RegKey.SetValue("NoControlPanel", true, RegistryValueKind.DWord); RegKey.Close();

        //registry
        RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
        Group Policy Objects\LocalUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
        RegKey.SetValue("DisableRegistryTools", true, RegistryValueKind.DWord); RegKey.Close();

        RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
        RegKey.SetValue("DisableRegistryTools", true, RegistryValueKind.DWord); RegKey.Close();
        return true;
```

Comment: Use a group policy object. Explorer recognizes GPOs and refreshes the policy cache when a GPO is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run [Gpupdate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490983.aspx) after you made the registry changes. This should in theory reload the group policy details and therefore disable the control panel.

Comment: thanks for ur response, Gpupdate  wont work
    gpedit /Target:User /force
    gpedit /Target:computer /force
any other method

Answer (score 0):

The following code will disable:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer");
                regkey.SetValue("NoControlPanel", true, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                regkey.Close();

            regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer");
            regkey.SetValue("NoControlPanel", true, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            regkey.Close();
```

And the code to re-enable:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer");
                regkey.SetValue("NoControlPanel", false, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                regkey.Close();

            regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer");
            regkey.SetValue("NoControlPanel", false, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            regkey.Close();
```